# Option value not getting passed (.NET + Ajax)

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax

I have a dropdown where I use ajax to fetch the select options.

```
<form asp-action="AdresWijzigen">

    <input asp-for="KlantId" hidden />
    <input asp-for="AdresType" hidden />
    <input asp-for="OudStraat" hidden />
    <input asp-for="OudHuisNummer" hidden />
    <input asp-for="OudBus" hidden />
    <input asp-for="OudPlaatsId" hidden />
    <input asp-for="OudPlaatsNaam" hidden />


    <div>
        <label asp-for="NieuwStraat"></label>
        <span asp-validation-for="NieuwStraat" class="text-danger"></span>
        <input asp-for="NieuwStraat" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label asp-for="NieuwHuisNummer"></label>
        <span asp-validation-for="NieuwHuisNummer" class="text-danger"></span>
        <input asp-for="NieuwHuisNummer" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label asp-for="NieuwBus"></label>
        <input asp-for="NieuwBus" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Postcode</label>
        <input type="text" id="postcodeInput" name="postcodeInput" placeholder="Geef een postcode in" />
        <input type="button" id="zoekGemeente" name="zoekGemeente" value="" />
        <p id="errorPostcode" class="text-danger" style="display:none"></p>

        <div id="gemeenteSelect"></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Adres wijzigen" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

```
    <script>
        $("#zoekGemeente").click(function () {
            var url = "@Url.Action("FetchGemeenteObvPostcode", "Klant")";
            var data = $("#postcodeInput").val();
            var $postcodeControl = /^\d{4}$/;

            if (data.match($postcodeControl)) {
                $("#errorPostcode").css('display', 'none');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    data: { postcode: $("#postcodeInput").val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.length < 1) {
                            $("#errorPostcode").css('display', 'inline-block');
                            $("#errorPostcode").text("Geen gemeente gevonden voor postcode " + $("#postcodeInput").val());
                            $("#gemeenteSelect").empty();
                        } else {
                            var g = '<select asp-for="NieuwPlaatsId">';
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                g += '<option value="' + data[i].plaatsId + '">' + data[i].plaatsNaam + '</option>';
                            }
                            g += '</select>';
                            $("#gemeenteSelect").html(g);
                        }
                    }
                })
            } else {
                $("#errorPostcode").css('display', 'inline-block');
                $("#errorPostcode").text("Geldige postcode moet uit 4 cijfers bestaan");
                $("#gemeenteSelect").empty();
            }
        })
    </script>
```

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult FetchGemeenteObvPostcode(string postcode)
        {
            var gemeentes = klantenRepository.GetPlaatsenByPostcodes(postcode);
            return Json(gemeentes);
        }

        //Valideer viewModel, als valid redirect naar WijzigenAdresBevestigen()
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult AdresWijzigen(AdresWijzigenViewModel viewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(WijzigingAdresBevestigen),viewModel);
            }
            else
            {
                List<Plaats> plaatsen = new List<Plaats>();
                plaatsen = _context.Plaatsen.ToList();
                ViewData["NieuwAdres"] = plaatsen;

                return View(viewModel);
            }
        }

// Redirect to page that requests confirmation
        public async Task<IActionResult> WijzigingAdresBevestigen(AdresWijzigenViewModel viewModel)
        {
            var nieuwPlaats = await _context.Plaatsen.FindAsync(viewModel.NieuwPlaatsId);
            Console.WriteLine(nieuwPlaats);
            ViewData["NieuwPlaatsNaam"] = nieuwPlaats.PlaatsNaam;
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

The fetch works fine, and the html select option value gets filled with the correct id's. However, when I submit the form, the option value that is filled in using ajax does not get filled into the model that is passed to the controller.

```
ViewData["NieuwPlaatsNaam"] = nieuwPlaats.PlaatsNaam;
```

^ this is the line that returns a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error on submit

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please include your form and submit code.

Comment: I wonder if it is actually possible to dynamically create an `<select asp-for="...">` element in the browser using javascript code. Maybe it can be done (I'm not an ASP .NET Core expert), but if I were you, I'd start by making very sure that it is actually possible and supported.

Comment: @PeterB Ah, is that so.. I'm a rookie myself so I didn't even consider that a possibility, I suppose I should look into that!

Comment: The `asp-for` part tells MVC to do 'special' things for elements that are adorned with such a directive, but I'm not familiar enough to say if your approach is supported by MVC or if it is doomed to fail because of that.

Comment: @PeterB It seems you're probably right. I figured it would be easier to just add the <select> in the html and toggle hide it if it's empty using javascript. It works fine now. Thank you for bringing this to my attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding the `<select asp-for=...>` tag in the HTML directly, as it seems that the `asp-for` doesn't work when added using Javascript (as pointed out by @PeterB in the comments).

```
    <div>
        <label>Postcode</label>
        <input type="text" id="postcodeInput" name="postcodeInput" placeholder="Geef een postcode in" />
        <input type="button" id="zoekGemeente" name="zoekGemeente" value="" />
        <p id="errorPostcode" class="text-danger" style="display:none"></p>

        **<select id="gemeenteSelect" asp-for="NieuwPlaatsId" style="display:none"></select>**
    </div>
```

```
....
                        if (data.length < 1) {
                            $("#errorPostcode").css('display', 'inline-block');
                            $("#errorPostcode").text("Geen gemeente gevonden voor postcode " + $("#postcodeInput").val());
                            $("#gemeenteSelect").css('display', 'none');
                        } else {
                            var g = '';
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                g += '<option value="' + data[i].plaatsId + '">' + data[i].plaatsNaam + '</option>';
                            }
                            $("#gemeenteSelect").css('display', 'inline-block');
                            $("#gemeenteSelect").append(g);
                        }
....
```